# Why doesn't Fabric see my .bash_profile?

Tags: fabric, bash

In Fabric, when I try to use any alias' or functions from my `.bash_profile` file, they are not recognized. For instance my `.bash_profile` contains `alias c='workon django-canada'`, so when I type `c` in iTerm or Terminal, `workon django-canada` is executed.

My `fabfile.py` contains

```
def test():
    local('c')
```

But when I try `fab test` it throws this at me:
    [localhost] local: c

```
/bin/sh: c: command not found

Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 127) while executing 'c'

Aborting.
```

Other Fabric functions work fine. Do I have to specify my bash profile somewhere in fabric?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

EDIT - As it turns out, this was fixed in Fabric 1.4.4. From the changelog:

> [Feature] [#725](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/725): Updated local to allow override of which local shell is used. Thanks to Mustafa Khattab.

So the original question would be fixed like this:

```
def test():
    local('c', shell='/bin/bash')
```

I've left my original answer below, which only relates to Fabric version < 1.4.4.

---

Because local doesn't use bash.  You can see it clearly in your output

```
/bin/sh: c: command not found
```

See?  It's using `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash`.  This is because Fabric's `local` command behaves a little differently internally than `run`.  The `local` command is essentially a wrapper around the `subprocess.Popen` python class.

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constuctor

And here's your problem.  Popen defaults to `/bin/sh`.  It's possible to specify a different shell if you are calling the Popen constructor yourself, but you're using it through Fabric.  And unfortunately for you, Fabric gives you no means to pass in a shell, like `/bin/bash`.

Sorry that doesn't offer you a solution, but it should answer your question.

EDIT

Here is the code in question, pulled directly from fabric's `local` function defined in the `operations.py` file:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd_arg, shell=True, stdout=out_stream,
    stderr=err_stream)
(stdout, stderr) = p.communicate()
```

As you can see, it does NOT pass in anything for the executable keyword.  This causes it to use the default, which is /bin/sh.  If it used bash, it'd look like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd_arg, shell=True, stdout=out_stream,
    stderr=err_stream, executable="/bin/bash")
(stdout, stderr) = p.communicate()
```

But it doesn't.  Which is why they say the following in the documentation for local:

> local is simply a convenience wrapper around the use of the builtin Python subprocess module with shell=True activated. If you need to do anything special, consider using the subprocess module directly.

Comment: But the [Fabric docs](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/0.9.0/usage/env.html#shell) say: 
"shell  
Default: **/bin/bash** -l -c  
  
Value used as shell wrapper when executing commands with e.g. run. Must be able to exist in the form <env.shell> "<command goes here>" – e.g. the default uses Bash’s -c option which takes a command string as its value."

Comment: Yeah, the docs are referring to the commands run and sudo.  The local command works different than those behind the scenes.  I've edited the answer to show the code in question.

Comment: From version 1.6, Fabric allows to use shell you want. `local('source {venv} && pelican {content_path} -s pelicanconf.py -t {theme} && deactivate'.format(**env), shell='/bin/bash')` There is 'shell' option  for that.

Comment: @anzo The `shell` option in `local` doesn't allow you to specify flags (such as `bash -l -c "local command"` which would be needed to access an alias in the .bashrc . It works by default on `run` or `sudo`.

Answer (score 3):

One workaround is simply to wrap whatever command you have around a bash command:

```
@task
def do_something_local():
    local("/bin/bash -l -c 'run my command'")
```

If you need to do a lot of these, consider creating a [custom context manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1180665/471842).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use virtualenvwrapper locally. You'll need to make your local command string look like this:

```
    local("/bin/bash -l -c 'workon django-canada && python manage.py runserver'")
```

Here's an example by yours truly [that does that for you in a context manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18397479/456848).