# Moving hidden files in Fabric

Tags: python, sh, fabric

I want to use Fabric to chown all the files in a directory - including hidden files.  Since Fabric uses the sh shell and not bash and sh doesn't know shopt, I can't do:

```
local('shopt -s dotglob')
local('sudo chown -R name dir')
```

I don't think there is a way to use the bash shell in Fabric.  Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using another strategy to recursively chown everything in the directory, including hidden files and directories:

```
local('sudo find dir -exec chown name {} \;')
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That looks good, thanks. Could you explain what the "{} \;" does?

Comment: You are welcome. It works like `xargs` - needed for passing the next result of find to the `chown`. In other words `{}` will be replaced with the next file/dir name. `\;` is greatly explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6085237/771848).

Comment: Another alternative from [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005348/why-doesnt-fabric-see-my-bash-profile]:   `local("/bin/bash -l -c 'shopt -s dotglob'")`

Comment: Also in more recent versions of Fabric (1.6 at least and I am using 1.3), the local function accepts shell as a keyword parameter.