# Getting a Python Virtual Environment, Fabric and Sudo to Work Together

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, zsh, fabric

Steps to reproduce:

1. In a linux environment, create a folder on your desktop called 'fab'
2. FYI, I'm using zsh
3. cd to `~/Desktop/fab`
4. Run this `fabfile.py` made in your ./fab dir by issuing `fab init`:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   #set up ssh to remote server

   import sys, os, fileinput
   from fabric.api import *

   def init():
       local('mkdir ./virtualenv')
       local('cd ./virtualenv && virtualenv --no-site-packages venv')
       local('chown -R user:user ./virtualenv/')
       local('chmod 770 -R ./virtualenv/')
       venv = 'source ./virtualenv/venv/bin/activate && '
       local(venv+'pip install mysql-python django South')
   ```
5. Get this error:

   ```
   ➜  fab  fab init    
   [localhost] local: mkdir ./virtualenv
   [localhost] local: cd ./virtualenv && virtualenv --no-site-packages venv
   New python executable in venv/bin/python
   Installing distribute...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................done.
   Installing pip................done.
   [localhost] local: chown -R user:user ./virtualenv/
   [lcalhost] local: chmod 770 -R ./virtualenv/
   [localhost] local: source ./virtualenv/venv/bin/activate && pip install mysql-python django South
   /bin/sh: 1: source: not found

   Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 127) while executing 'source ./virtualenv/venv/bin/activate && pip install mysql-python django South'

   Aborting.
   ```
6. Run `source ./virtualenv/venv/bin/activate && pip install mysql-python django South` from zsh, and observe that it works.

This is not a duplicate question of something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180411/activate-a-virtualenv-via-fabric-as-deploy-user), as I am getting the same error even if I use a `with prefix(` in my code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `source` with `/bin/bash/`. Here's an example:

```
from fabric.api import *


def init():
    local('virtualenv --no-site-packages venv')

    venv_command = '/bin/bash venv/bin/activate'
    pip_command = 'venv/bin/pip install mysql-python django South'
    local(venv_command + ' && ' + pip_command)
```

FYI, for `run/sudo` it's better to use `prefix` context manager, like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5359988/771848).

Hope that helps.

Comment: breaking up the commands into two variables like that also made a difference.

Comment: This kind of works, but not completely. `pip_command` projects are not installing- the system now just tries to install to the system, but not the virtual environment (even if `fab init` is run as a non-root user).

Comment: How about using `venv/bin/pip` instead of just `pip`?

Comment: the `pip_command` is being run outside the virtualenv. Structure it [like so](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18397763/456848): `local("/bin/bash -l -c 'source venv/bin/activate && python manage.py runserver'")`