# conda virtual environment with fabric2

Tags: python, conda, fabric

I would like to use a conda virtual environment with fabric2. I see some advice for [fabric1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795618/getting-a-python-virtual-environment-fabric-and-sudo-to-work-together#17796186) and some [packages](https://pypi.org/project/fabric-virtualenv/) to handle this. But it seems like there should be an easy way to do this with fabric2. Normally I activate with `$source activate myenv`

Comment: I wonder if my solution was helpful?!

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you have already created the virtual environment, then what you have to do is:

from fabric import task

```
@task(hosts=["servername"])
def do_things(c):
    with c.cd('your_dir'):
        # assuming you already added myenv to your path 
        with c.prefix('source activate myenv'): 
            c.run('pip3.6 install -r requirements.txt') #for example if you have pip3.6
```

You have to use `with c.prefix()` to enable using that environment! And remember you have to run everything within the scope of `with c.prefix('source activate myenv'):` if you want to use the virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

@Peshmerge's answer works for me. But we do need to keep in mind that fabric2 would use the default bash shell. If you use `conda init zsh` before, you have to do it again for the bash shell: `conda init bash`.