# Invoking bash aliases in Fabric scripts

Tags: ubuntu, alias, fabric

I have aliases in a `~/.bash_aliases` file on a remote ubuntu server. The file is loaded in the standard way from a `~/.bashrc` file, like so:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

That `~/.bashrc` file in turn is loaded (also in a standard way) from a `~/.profile` file which looks like this:

```
if [ "$BASH" ]; then
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
    echo ".profile loaded .bashrc"
  fi
fi
mesg n
```

I've found that my aliases were unavailable in my fabric commands, e.g. when I do this in a fabric script:

```
run("aliased_command")
```

I get this output:

```
run: aliased_command
out: .profile loaded .bashrc
out: /bin/bash: aliased_command: command not found
Fatal error: run() encountered an error (return code 127) while executing 'aliased_command'
```

Now I managed to reproduce this outside of fabric by logging into the server with ssh, and running :

```
~# /bin/bash -l -c aliased_command
```

from the shell (n.b. `/bin/bash -l -c` is fabric's default, see [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.0/usage/env.html#shell)) I get the same output:

```
.profile loaded .bashrc:
/bin/bash: aliased_command: command not found
```

After a fair bit of searching on related topics, I read somewhere that aliases aren't exported for non-interactive shells, and I then managed to fix this using `/bin/bash -l -c -i` (`-i` sets bash to interactive mode).

I then added the following to my fabfile.py:

```
env.shell = "/bin/bash -l -c -i"
```

Now I can use aliases in my fabric commands... just great!

---

So my questions are:

- Are there any problems with this solution? If so, what should I be doing?
- Does anyone else have a problem running aliases in their fabfiles?
- Is there any obvious reason why I might have this issue and others wouldn't?
- Can anyone point me to links etc. that describe this problem and a resolution? And also explain how they found them... : )

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is the quick answer to the main issue, to save someone reading my long question, just
add

```
env.shell = "/bin/bash -l -i -c"
```

to your fabfile.py and you should be able use aliases in your fabric commands just great!

Comment: I think in the interests of people getting stuff done, this seems to be the best workaround for the problem most people coming here will be looking to solve (assuming there's no major issue using -i). However the other answers were quite helpful to me for the specific questions asked, so thank you kindly and I've upvoted your answers accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you are perfectly correct that by default aliases are not expanded by the bash shell in non interactive session.

See section on alias in man page: http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

> Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the
>   expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt (see the description of
>   shopt under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).

So to allow this to happen on an non-interactive session, include this in your `.profile`.

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

This will make aliases available in non-interactive session and your fabric scripts without resorting to interactive sessions.

Comment: Ok cool, that makes sense, but for some reason this isn't working for me, after adding the above to my .profile, I still get command not found for all alias commands in my fabfile if I don't use -i. Do you see any problem with using bash's -i flag in my fabfile?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the reasoning behind bash's behavior of not exporting aliases is that aliases are designed primarily to provide a mechanism for interactive shell users to define quick shortcuts or abbreviations. In your scripts, you should be using the full commands (i.e. `ls -l` instead of `ll`) for readability. Don't make folks learn all your aliases in order to read your project's source. If your aliases are really so crucial, consider making them standalone shell scripts or at least shell functions. I think you will find it extremely uncommon to use aliases in non-interactive source code, and perhaps you should reconsider your implementation.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is what I was expecting might be the case, and fits my evidence of not many others having this problem, cheers. Having said that, most of our stuff is in functions, and they are seemingly inaccessible too... So I think I'm going to have to stick with -i for now, with appropriate commenting on each function/alias in my fabfile.