# Automating virtualenv and Django development server startup with fabric?

Tags: django, virtualenv, fabric

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Activate a virtualenv via fabric as deploy user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180411/activate-a-virtualenv-via-fabric-as-deploy-user)

I've been advised to try and use fabric for deploying Django to a production server, and automating tasks by using python instead of bash.

I wanted to start easily and just automate the activation of my virtualenv, and start the Django development server in it.

I've created a file named fabfile.py:

```
from fabric.api import local

def activate_env():
    local("source /.../expofit_env/bin/activate")

def run_local_server():
    local("/.../server/manage.py runserver")

def start():
    activate_env()
    run_local_server()
```

However, when I run

```
fab start
```

i get the following message:

```
[localhost] local: source /.../expofit_env/bin/activate
/bin/sh: 1: source: not found

Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 127) while executin
'source /.../expofit_env/bin/activate'
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Update**

Based on Burhan Khalid's proposal, i tried the following:

```
....
def activate_env():
    local("/bin/bash /.../expofit_env/bin/activate")
....
```

Running just

```
fab activate_env
```

results:

```
[localhost] local: /bin/bash /.../expofit_env/bin/activate

Done.
```

However after execution, virtualenv isn't activated.
For the following code:

```
def start_env(): 
    with prefix('/bin/bash /.../expofit_env/bin/activate'): 
        local("yolk -l")
```

I still get an error, as if virtualenv wasn't activated.

```
alan@linux ~/Desktop/expofit $ fab start_env
[localhost] local: yolk -l
/bin/sh: 1: yolk: not found
```

When i manually activate virtualenv, yolk workd fine:

```
alan@linux ~/.../expofit_env $ source bin/activate
(expofit_env)alan@linux ~/.../expofit_env $ yolk -l

DateUtils       - 0.5.2        - active 
Django          - 1.4.1        - active 
Python          - 2.7.3rc2     - active development (/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload)
....
```

---

**Update**

Tried a new approach from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180411/activate-a-virtualenv-via-fabric-as-deploy-user?rq=1).

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from fabric.api import *
from contextlib import contextmanager as _contextmanager

env.activate = 'source /.../expofit_env/bin/activate'

@_contextmanager
def virtualenv():
    with prefix(env.activate):
        yield

def deploy():
    with virtualenv():
        local('yolk -l')
```

Gives the same error:

```
[localhost] local: yolk -l
/bin/sh: 1: source: not found

Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 127) while executing 'yolk -l'

Aborting.
```

Even dough the first command passes without errors:

```
alan@linux ~/.../expofit_env/bin $ fab virtualenv

[servername] Executing task 'virtualenv'

Done.
```

**Update**

It is possible to run the `local` with a custom shell.

```
from fabric.api import local

def start_env():
        local('source env/bin/activate',shell='/bin/bash')
```

However, that didn't activate the virtualenv as if it was done manually.

Comment: remove `source`, it should be `/bin/bash /path/to/bin/activate`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid It runs without errors, however it doesn't activate the virtualenv.

Comment: The code is:
    `def start_env():`
        `with prefix('/bin/bash /.../expofit_env/bin/activate'):`

I run it with `fab start_env`
            `local("yolk -l")`

Comment: You keep using `source`, which is why you keep getting the same error.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I updated the question. Check the section related with the first update (the one updated based on your recommendation). No `source` there. The second update is a solution based on the second answer.

Comment: @Alan -- did you ever get an answer to this question?  the code in the "duplicate" question generates the same error you're describing (basically, that fabric is trying to invoke `source` using `sh` as a shell -- despite my `env.shell` being set correctly).

Comment: @simon what's your `env.shell`? `/bin/bash -l -c` should do it.

Comment: @simon Found something new. But not the solution yet. Updating question.

Comment: @simon Tried running `source env/bin/activate` as a shell script also doesnt activate virtualenv.

Comment: @simon Found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6944649/1214214) works for a bash script. Now we have to figure out how to do the `--rcfile` through fabric.

Comment: @Alan I had exactly the same problem with you. I solved problem as following.

`#!/bin/bash` `def workon(): local("/bin/bash --rcfile /home/{USERNAME}/.virtualenvs/{VIRTUALENV NAME}/bin/activate")`

Comment: `with prefix('. /path/to/activate')`

Answer (score 3):

To use enable a virtualenv from the fab file you need to run your commands as follow:

```
def task():

    # do some things outside the env if needed 

    with prefix('source bin/activate'):
        # do some stuff inside the env
        pip install django-audiofield
```

All the commands within the with bloc will be executed inside the virtualenv

Comment: It didn't work. Resulted the same "/bin/sh: 1: source: not found
" error.

Answer (score 2):

By default you are using the `sh` shell, and the `source` command is a bashism (that is, something that only works in bash).

To activate your environment, you need to execute it with bash directly. `/bin/bash /path/to/bin/activate`.

Comment: Updated the question based on your proposal.

Comment: @Alan is correct -- while this answer is relevant, it does not solve the problem