# Can't install packages using pip in Virtualenv on remote using Fabric

Tags: deployment, virtualenv, fabric

I have being using fabric to deploy an app with virtualenv. I was using fabric 1.4 and upgraded to 1.5.1 last week. My script stopped working.

It can't install the requirements. It seems it's not activating the virtualenv. In my code, I have:

```
with cd('%(path)s' % env):
        with prefix('source bin/activate'):
            run('pip install -U distribute')
```

I'm getting a permission denied error: `error: could not delete '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py': Permission denied`

The command being executed is:

```
Executed: /bin/bash -l -c "cd /var/www/myproject && source bin/activate && export PATH=\"\\$PATH:\\"/var/www/myproject\\" \" && pip install -U distribute"
```

If I ssh to the remote machine and run `cd /var/www/myproject && source bin/activate && pip install -U distribute`, it works just fine.

Why is my fabric script not working?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have a slight suspicion that having fabric instantiate a virtualenv on a target host might have unwanted results..

Comment: According to this link, it's possible, but I don't get what I'm doing wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180411/activate-a-virtualenv-via-fabric-as-deploy-user

Comment: Well, the only difference is, you're using `run()`, rather than `sudo()`, which might be a permission issue. Try using `sudo()`?

Comment: it's strange, because as I'm in a virtualenv, it should not require sudo

Comment: It depends who created the virtualenv and whether you can do it as your own user. Other point is, fabric really executes command with that `/bin/bash -l -c "..."` prefix, if you do that as the user fabric uses on the machine, does it work as well?

Comment: using sudo, the packages are not installed in the virtualenv. I'm using the same user as fabric

Comment: Aha, so basically it means sourcing the venv fails. What if you do `source /full/path/to/bin/activate` instead of relative path? Despite the `with cd()`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of the serial approach with..

```
source bin/activate
pip install -U distribute
```

..directly use the pip executable of the virtualenv:

```
myenv/bin/pip install -U distribute
```

Answer (score 3):

Although not exactly a solution, [fabtools](https://github.com/ronnix/fabtools) has a number of functions related to virtualenvs that are very handy. They do (almost) all of the hard work for you, and are probably worth using to check it isn't something else going wrong.

```
# Cut (and modified) from the fabtools documentation
from fabric.api import *
from fabtools import require
import fabtools

@task
def setup():
    # Require a Python package
    with fabtools.python.virtualenv('/home/myuser/env'):
        require.python.package('pyramid')
```