# fabric returning 127 with "source" command

Tags: python, fabric

I just can't figure out why this is happening...

in my fabric file I have this...

```
def func():
    local("source ../venv/bin/activate")
```

It is returning 127 on the source command and I am not sure why, when i try to run source in my terminal manually it works. When I try a different command in fabric, like...

```
local("echo 'foo'")
```

it also works. Why would source be causing problems? I can't see any reason why this would be happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`source` is unknown by `sh`. If you want to run a command in the context of a virtual environment, use Fabric's context managers and run the `activate` binary without source. I've adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5359988/2178164).

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from fabric.api import *
from contextlib import contextmanager as _contextmanager

env.activate = '. ./.env/bin/activate'

@_contextmanager
def virtualenv():
    with prefix(env.activate):
        yield

def deploy():
    with virtualenv():
        local('echo hello world!')
```